# Is it necessary to detach or delete a source in Stripe if its single use?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

when I make a one-time transaction I create a source for the user with the option `usage: single_use` I was wondering if it's necessary to delete it afterwards (or detach it).

I don't fully understand the difference between deleting a card or detaching, or even if it's necessary at this point.

Comment: I suggest contacting the Stripe team on IRC, they are super friendly, helpful, and quick to respond with detail. https://stripe.com/contact  #stripe on freenode

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will do and answer here with their response.

Answer (score 2):

If you set `usage` to `single_use` when creating a Source it can only be used once.  [Stripe recommends you do not attach single use Sources to Customers](https://stripe.com/docs/sources#single-use-or-reusable):

> Conversely, if a source can only be used once, this parameter is set to `single_use`, and a source must be created each time a customer makes a payment. Such sources should not be attached to customers—instead, they should be charged directly. They can be charged only once, and their status will change to consumed when charged.

That said, if you do attach them to Customers, there's no real need to detach them, they simply won't work beyond their first use.